# Falla al insertar campos en mysql con PHP con un metodo post

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en PHP pero cuando hago la inserción de datos con el método post marca el error  "Call to a member function query() on null" .

$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$Descripcion = $_POST['des'];
$codigo = $_POST['cb'];
$pc = $_POST['pc'];
$Mayoreo = $_POST['pma'];
$Menudeo = $_POST['pmu'];
$sugerido = $_POST['sugerido'];

$insert ="INSERT INTO producto (clave ,Descripcion ,Codigo ,pc ,Mayoreo ,Menudeo , sugerido)values(      '$clave','$Descripcion','$codigo','$pc','$Mayoreo','$Menudeo','$sugerido')";

$ejecutar =  $enlace->query($insert);
if(!ejecutar)
{
    printf("Error" , $enlace ->error);
}else {
    echo "se agrego correcto";
}

mysqli_close($enlace);
echo "Datos correctos";

¿Alguien que me ayude ya que no encuentro un error en mi código?

Comment: Donde está tu cadena de conexión? De donde sacas la variable enlace ?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Puede que el problema lo tengas por escribir incorrectamente la variable al obtener en post. Mira esta línea: `$sugerido = $_POST['sugerdio'];` debería ser así: `$sugerido = $_POST['sugerido']; o me equivoco y tienes un input llamado "sugerdio". Revisa esto por favor

Comment: También que el campo Mayoreo le estás insertando por defecto 'Mayoreo' es decir no una variable sino directamente un string. No sé si tenga que ver también con tu error ya que no conozco la estructura de tu tabla y por ende tampoco conozco que tipo de dato es cada campo.

Comment: Ya realice los cambios en el código  que me hicieron como cambiar el sugerido y agregar la variable a mayoreo pero hora tengo el problema " Call to a member function query() on null"

Answer (score 0):

Este mensaje de error significa que en la instrucción

`$ejecutar =  $enlace->query($insert);`

$enlace es nulo, asi que debes revisar el codigo 

`$enlace  = conectar();`

y ver que la función conectar este devolviendo un objeto valido